# Python - extract certificate from p7s file

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, pkcs#7, smime

Decoding an incoming email in Python, I have an attachment "smime.p7s".
If I write this to a file, then it can be extracted and viewed using

`openssl pkcs7 -inform der -print_certs <smime.p7s`

I'd like to do that in Python. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098879/8545455) of the inverse process, i.e. how to *sign* a mail.

Looking at the OpenSSL [API documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/PKCS7_get0_signers.html) there is an entry point `PKCS7_get0_signers` which seems to do this.

Here's the code snippet I'm trying, based on a naive reworking of the signing code.

```
with open(fname, 'wb') as p7sfile:
    p7sfile.write(sig)
    pkcs7 = crypto._lib.PKCS7_get0_signers(sig, None, 0)
```

It doesn't work - giving

```
pkcs7 = crypto._lib.PKCS7_get0_signers(sig, None, 0)
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'PKCS7 *' must be a cdata pointer, not bytes
```

The function seems to require three parameters, although maybe flags is optional?

[This line](https://github.com/appknox/m2crypto/blob/20878a7dcd57a18f5e30fdbb953a7ef3768aa27b/M2Crypto/SMIME.py#L73) of code (from the older M2Crypto library) also suggests that entry point needs three parameters.

I don't understand why it would need a "certs.stack" as an input param when we are trying to *extract* the certs, and I don't understand what to put in "flags".

I'm pretty sure I need some specially typed buffer declarations to set up the call, and also retrieve the results (like the `bio_in = crypto._new_mem_buf(data)` preamble in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098879/8545455)). Can someone please suggest how to do it?

Also - the `M2Crypto` library is not compatible with Python 3.x, hence looking for an alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract userCertificate from PKCS7 envelop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379846/extract-usercertificate-from-pkcs7-envelop-in-python)

Comment: Yes, that is related. but uses the older `M2Crypto` library which isn't Python 3.x compatible. I found a code snippet using the PyOpenSSL library below which I'll propose as a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a useful code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104923/pyopenssls-pkcs7-object-provide-very-little-information-how-can-i-get-the-sha1). This extracts certs from a PKCS7 binary object into a list of `OpenSSL.crypto.X509` objects.

The OpenSSL.crypto.X509 object is OK for dumping out the certificate contents (it has a `dump_certificate` method), but the attributes are hard to work with as they are still ASN.1 encoded and are C types.

Once you've got a list of certs, each can be converted into a `cryptography` `Certificate` object which is Python native and more amenable. For example:

```
class Cert(object):
    """
    Convenient container object for human-readable and output-file friendly certificate contents
    """
    pem = ''
    email_signer = None
    startT = None
    endT = None
    issuer = {}
    algorithm = None


def extract_smime_signature(payload):
    """
    Extract public certificates from the PKCS7 binary payload

    :param payload: bytes
    :return: list of Cert objects
    """
    pkcs7 = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, payload)
    certs = get_certificates(pkcs7)
    certList = []
    # Collect the following info from the certificates
    all_cert_times_valid = True
    for c in certs:
        # Convert to the modern & easier to use https://cryptography.io library objects
        c2 = crypto.X509.to_cryptography(c)
        c3 = Cert()

        # check each certificate's time validity, ANDing cumulatively across each one
        c3.startT = c2.not_valid_before
        c3.endT = c2.not_valid_after
        now = datetime.now()
        all_cert_times_valid = all_cert_times_valid and (c3.startT <= now) and (now <= c3.endT)

        # get Issuer, unpacking the ASN.1 structure into a dict
        for i in c2.issuer.rdns:
            for j in i:
                c3.issuer[j.oid._name] = j.value

        # get email address from the cert "subject" - consider more than one address in the bundle as an error
        for i in c2.subject.rdns:
            for j in i:
                attrName = j.oid._name
                if attrName == 'emailAddress':
                    c3.email_signer = j.value

        # Get hash alg - just for interest
        c3.algorithm = c2.signature_hash_algorithm.name
        c3.pem = c2.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM).decode('utf8')
        certList.append(c3)
    return certList
```

Comment: The checks on the certs made in this code are overly simplistic. With access to a trusted cert bundle (such as the file "ca-bundle.crt" available in many Linuxes) it's possible to do much better than this. It's work in progress, but see https://github.com/tuck1s/sparkySecure/blob/master/readSMIMEsig.py